# datatablesに新たな行を作成しようとするとエラーになってしまう

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

下記ソースで作成したtableに新たに行を追加しようと思い、

```js
 $.get(url, function (jsonData) {
     $('#example').DataTable({
        data: jsonData,
        columns: [
            { data: 'Name' },
            { data: 'Email' }
        ]
    });
 });
```

```html
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

[このサイトを参考に](http://qiita.com/Ki4mTaria/items/f309653da284628d0900)下記の方法で行追加の実装をしたのですが、

```js
var a = $('#example').DataTable;
$.get(url, function (jsonData) {
    data: jsonData,
    a.row.add([
        { data: 'FileName' },
        { data: 'Email' ｝
    ]).draw();
});
```

エラーが発生します。
エラー内容はCannot read property 'add' of undefinedです。

間違いを見つけられないのですが、解決方法の分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTable以前に文法が間違っているので、一度ちゃんとjavascriptの文法を勉強した方がよいと思います。

```
var a = $('#example').DataTable;
$.get(url, function (jsonData) {
    data: jsonData, <- 関数とオブジェクトがごっちゃになっている
    a.row.add([
        { data: 'FileName' }, <-このdataはラベルなので上のjsonDataとは何も関係ない
        { data: 'Email' ｝
    ]).draw();
});
```